# iphone thinks it's up to date when it's not

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

I have iOS 9.0.1 and today i want to update to 9.0.2 but my iPhone 6 thinks it's up to date. I was using all of the betas without any problem since iOS 9 beta 1 then i updated to GM version. I really don't wanna hard reset or iTunes update to my phone. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always find full lists of download links within 24 hours of a release going live.

9.0.2 is listed here - http://www.redmondpie.com/download-ios-9.0.2-links-for-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-ipsw/

The links are to Apple's own download servers - just make sure you pick the correct version for your device.

Initiate the update from iTunes by holding the  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  key as you click Check for Update & navigate to the file you just downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

1. Update iTunes to latest version
2. Wait few hours /a day and try again